# Transistion div on height change without jquery

Tags: html, css

I have a basic setup. When I increase the height, I get a smooth increase. When decreased, I **should** get a smooth decrease but instead a sharp decrease.

```
<div className="foo <!-- -->">Hey</div>
```

You may have noticed `className` and `<!-- -->`, I'm using react. `<!-- -->` gets replaced with the class to decrease the height.

```
// SCSS
.foo { 
 height 400px;
 // background props
 transition: all 250ms ease-out
}

.foo.decreaseClass {
  height: 40px;
  transition: all 250ms ease-in
}
```

When the new class is attached, the div becomes

```
<div className="foo decreaseClass">Hey</div>
```

How to get both transitions down/up?

Comment: It's better to show up a live demo

Comment: it seems to be fine as a first view, so better provide us with working snippet to see the behavior

Comment: Sorry. I'll do a fiddle in bit. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're not properly closing the `height` declaration in `.foo`. You're using a comma instead of a semi-colon, rendering both `height` and `transition` declarations invalid. Also note the same declaration should contain a `colon` between the style property name and its value (`height: 400px;`).

Therefore, your element only has defined `height` and `transition` only when having both classes.

See it working:

```js
document.querySelector('.foo').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.target.classList.toggle('decreaseClass')
})
```

```css
.foo {
  height: 200px;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  border: 1px solid
}

.foo.decreaseClass {
  height: 40px;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">Hey</div>
```

Comment: That's just a typo, I'll change

Comment: There are more *typo*s. `className` should be `class` and there should be a colon between `height` and it's value. Syntax is quite important in CSS. Here's your [curated code](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/nt2ggryd/). Apparently, working.

Comment: className should be fine i guess, it's React

Comment: @TemaniAfif, while that might well be the case, there is no mention of React in the question itself and `className` is not valid markup. Yet.

Comment: read the line before the code :) he mention this **You may have noticed className and <!-- -->, I'm using react**

Comment: @TemaniAfif:  yep, my bad. I missed it. In this case it must have been the missing colon. :)

Comment: Ok, how this was caused by the `colon` in your explanation for that worked? I so lost.

Comment: @Sylar: you don't have a colon in your CSS. It says: `height 400px;`

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS `@keyframe animation` and  `alternate` properties. `infinite` is added just for demo purposes. Instead of `height` I added `transform:scaleY(1)` to `(10)`.

### Demo

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden
}

.test {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white
}

.B {
  height: 40px;
  animation: animB 1s alternate infinite;
  transform-origin: top;

}

@keyframes animB {
  0% {
    transform: scaleY(1);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scaleY(10);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='test B'>TEST</div>
```

Comment: why he should use animation ? in his question the idea is to add a class that will decrease the height which seems fine .. so he need to show us what's wrong exactly

Comment: OP issue is that the div dec/increases 40px to 400px on one side it is smooth but on the alternate state there's no discernable transition.

Comment: yes and as you can see in his code, he's adding a class for this ... and it works in only one direction and no the other (but it should work also) so there is an issue with the code ... and actually you provided a completly new code/new way to do this which i thing is not a fix for his issue (i may be wrong)